# How to tell software which output to use?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, speakers

Anyone know of some software that'll let me set the default sound device for individual software?

When I'm on Ventrilo playing games with friends I have voice chat play through my headphones and all other noise play through my speakers. I also like to listen to music, but they frequently request I turn it down to the point where I can't even hear it. I was hoping for something that'd let me tell Winamp / Chrome to play audio through my headset (for when I'm on voice chat) or my speakers easily (for when I'm not). I've got my speakers set as my Default Audio Device in Windows, and my headset as the Default Comm Device.

I wish I simply drag the icons from 1 source to the other in the default Windows mixer, but alas.

Comment: AFAIK, the Windows API does support this, but the application must be using the updated APIs.

Comment: @surfasb Would you by chance know of any media player that does that, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used two players: FooBar and WinAmp. Both of them, in their Preferences, offer you the choice of what is called "the Output Device".

With either of the players you should be able to "move the music" into your head set.

In FooBar you'd have to go to File -> Preferences -> Playback -> Output and select the device you want to output to. You'll have to make some tests until you get it through your head set (in me experience those device names can be pretty strange so you'd have to guess what is what).

In WinAmp in a bit more Complex to find it. It is in Options -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Output. There you should activate Direct Sound [out_ds.dll] and click "Configure". In the new dialog you will be able to select your output device.

I suspect other players would have similar settings where you select your output device. But this would a "per player" configuration. I do not think you can do it from the Windows Mixer.

Comment: The Windows Mixer will not (and probably never) do that.  Many programs still use the legacy APIs and you risk crashing.